# SQL syntax for update query with connect by prior

Tags: oracle, hierarchical-query

I start to work with SQL and I faced up with hierarchical queries. meanwhile I success to select the rows with `connect by prior` command but failed to update. Here is my update query:

```
update HTABLE set status = 'INACTIVE'
  WHERE STATUS <> 'CLOSE'
  Connect by prior PARENT_ID=ID start with PARENT_ID=12345;
```

I got `SQL Error: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended`. How can I update table hierarchically?

### Edit

I also tried to put the `where` condition in the `start with`, but it does not help:

```
update HTABLE set status = 'INACTIVE'
  Connect by prior PARENT_ID=ID start with PARENT_ID=12345 AND STATUS <> 'CLOSE';
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The hierarchical query only works with SELECT. It doesn't work with UPDATE (I agree it could be neat if it did).

So what you can do is this:

```
update HTABLE 
set status = 'INACTIVE'
WHERE STATUS <> 'CLOSE'
and id in ( select c.id
            from htable
            connect by prior ID = PARENT_ID 
            start with PARENT_ID = 12345);
```

Note the order of columns `connect by prior ID = PARENT_ID`. Normally we want to walk down the tree from the START WITH row, which is what I've done. Your ordering `connect by prior PARENT_ID = ID` walks up the tree from 12345 to its parents, grandparents, etc. If that's what you want, switch the `connect by` clause back.

Answer (score 1):

You can update using clause `where id in (select ... connect by...)` or you can use `merge`:

```
merge into htable h
using (select distinct id 
         from htable 
         where status <> 'CLOSE'
         connect by prior parent_id = id 
         start with parent_id = 11) src
on (h.id = src.id)
when matched then update set status = 'INACTIVE'
```

Test data:

```
create table htable (id number(4), parent_id number(4), status varchar2(10));
insert into htable values (   1, null, 'ACTIVE');
insert into htable values (  11,    1, 'CLOSE');
insert into htable values (  12,    1, 'ACTIVE');
insert into htable values ( 111,   11, 'ACTIVE');
insert into htable values ( 112,   11, 'ACTIVE');
insert into htable values ( 121,   12, 'ACTIVE');
insert into htable values (   2, null, 'ACTIVE');
insert into htable values (  21,    2, 'ACTIVE');
insert into htable values ( 211,   21, 'ACTIVE');
insert into htable values ( 212,   21, 'ACTIVE');
```

and after `merge`:

```
   ID PARENT_ID STATUS
----- --------- ----------
    1           INACTIVE
   11         1 INACTIVE
   12         1 ACTIVE
  111        11 INACTIVE
  112        11 INACTIVE
  121        12 ACTIVE
    2           ACTIVE
   21         2 ACTIVE
  211        21 ACTIVE
  212        21 ACTIVE
```